# Stored procedure with select as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to ask a little question: I have a stored procedure called `SP_CARGA_NUEVOS`.

To use this stored procedure, I need a string in this format: `'AD18010611'`.

The last 4 digits of the string are the current month and day, so instead of changing the value manually I wrote this little query:

```
SELECT 
    'AD1801' +  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GETDATE(), 101) + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Which returns `AD18010611`

But when I try to use the stored procedure, I get an error:

> Procedure or function 'SP_CARGA_NUEVOS' expects parameter '@COMENTARIO', which was not supplied.

My question: is there a way to send a select as a parameter to a stored procedure?

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

I am calling the SP like this

```
Exec dbo.SP_CARGA_NUEVOS select 'AD1801'+ convert(varchar(2), GETDATE(), 101) + 
convert(varchar(2), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Which is not working.

The right way is:

```
Exec dbo.SP_CARGA_NUEVOS 'AD18010611'
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also, please **show us** exactly **how** you call your stored procedure! That'll be the point where something seems to be going wrong - and remember: we cannot see your screen, nor read your mind - you have to *show us*!

Comment: I did not make the Store procedure, just trying to automate some things

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** have expressions or selects in the middle of the `EXEC` - you need to *first* select the value you want to use into a variable, and then call your stored procedure - like this:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(20);

SELECT @Input = 'AD1801' +
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GETDATE(), 101) + 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GETDATE(), 103)

EXEC dbo.SP_CARGA_NUEVOS @Input
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a stored procedure with a query output directly, as you are trying to do here. Note that in the description of the EXECUTE call's syntax, parameter usage is defined as:

```
    [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                       | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                       | [ DEFAULT ]   
                       }
```

Translating, this says you can use a constant value, a variable, or accept the default value (if there is one). Accepting the output of a query is not an option.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the return of the select could be considered a variable

Comment: Haha, thanks again for the fast answer, I'll upvote the answer when I get enough reputation